# Recognise operator and perform calculation

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this problem:

Write a simple interpreter which understands "+", "-", and "*" operations. Apply the operations in order
using command/arg pairs starting with the initial value of `value`. If you encounter an unknown command, return -1. You are to ignore B.O.D.M.A.S completely.

```
Examples of the input and output
interpret(1, ["+"], [1]) → 2
interpret(4, ["-"], [2]) → 2
interpret(1, ["+", "*"], [1, 3]) → 6
interpret(5, ["+", "*", "-"], [4, 1, 3]) → 6
```

I have tried passing the parameters as multidimensional arrays below. I am trying to solve the problem such that when I do this

```
let operator = ["+", "-"];
let integer = 1;
let intArr = [1, 2];
let emptyInt;
let anotherInt;
let newArray = [integer, operator, intArr];
```

How do I make this work like above? Adding each of the array sequentially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).`ac` to first value. And then add/minus/divide/multiply by by checking the operator.

```js
function interpret(...args){
  let operators = args[1]; //get the operators array
  let values = args[2] //numbers expect the first one.
  return values.reduce((ac,val,i) =>{
    //check the operator at the 'i' on which we are on while iterating through 'value'
    if(operators[i] === '+') return ac + val;
    else if(operators[i] === '-') return ac - val;
    else if(operators[i] === '*') return ac * val;
    else if(operators[i] === '/') return ac / val;
    else return -1;
  },args[0]) //'ac' is initially set to first value.
}

console.log(interpret(1, ["+"], [1])) 
console.log(interpret(4, ["-"], [2])) 
console.log(interpret(1, ["+", "*"], [1, 3])) 
console.log(interpret(5, ["+", "*", "-"], [4, 1, 3]))
```

Comment: Good but how do i return -1 if there is an unidentified operator

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [recursive approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)). Firstly, you can define an object to map your operators to useable functions, and then call a recursive function to calculate your result:

```js
const oper = {
  '+': (a, b) => a + b,
  '-': (a, b) => a - b,
  '*': (a, b) => a * b,
  '/': (a, b) => a / b
};

const interpret = (n, [fc, ...calcs], [fn, ...nums]) =>
  fc === undefined ? n :
  interpret(oper[fc](n, fn), calcs, nums)

console.log(interpret(1, ["+"], [1])); // 2
console.log(interpret(4, ["-"], [2])); // 2
console.log(interpret(1, ["+", "*"], [1, 3])); // 6
console.log(interpret(5, ["+", "*", "-"], [4, 1, 3])); // 6
```

If returning `-1` for invalid operands is a must you can use the following:

```js
const oper = {
  '+': (a, b) => a + b,
  '-': (a, b) => a - b,
  '*': (a, b) => a * b,
  '/': (a, b) => a / b
};

const interpret = (n, [fc, ...calcs], [fn, ...nums]) => {
  if(fc === undefined) return n;
  if(!(fc in oper)) return -1;
  return interpret(oper[fc](n, fn), calcs, nums)
}

console.log(interpret(1, ["+"], [1])); // 2
console.log(interpret(4, ["-"], [2])); // 2
console.log(interpret(1, ["+", "*"], [1, 3])); // 6
console.log(interpret(5, ["+", "*", "-"], [4, 1, 3])); // 6
console.log(interpret(1, ["+", "%"], [1, 2])); // -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object with the needed functions for the operators and redue the array by taking the value and an operand.

```js
const
    fns = {
        '+': (a, b) => a + b,
        '-': (a, b) => a - b,
        '*': (a, b) => a * b,
        '/': (a, b) => a / b
    },
    interpret = (start, operators, values) =>
        values.reduce(
            (a, b, i) => operators[i] in fns
                ? fns[operators[i]](a, b)
                : - 1,
            start
        );

console.log(interpret(1, ["+"], [1])); // 2
console.log(interpret(4, ["-"], [2])); // 2
console.log(interpret(1, ["+", "*"], [1, 3])); // 6
console.log(interpret(5, ["+", "*", "-"], [4, 1, 3])); // 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:--

```
function getOperator(number, operator, integer) {
    let result;
    switch (operator) {
        case '+':
            result = number + integer;
            break;
        case '-':
            result = number - integer;
            break;
        case '*':
            result = number * integer;
            break;
        case '/':
            result = number / integer;
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
function doOperation(array) {
    number = array[0];
    for (let i = 0; i < array[1].length; i++) {
        number = getOperator(number, array[1][i], array[2][i]);
    }
    return number;
}
```

You can then use this to achieve asked :--

```
doOperation([1, ["+"], [1]])
```